# Using Java14 to manually compile the module, but an error is reported

Tags: java, javac, java-module, java-14, module-info

I wrote a very simple Example of a Java module following the tutorial, but when using the javac command, I didn't get an error, and when compiling with the Java command, I got an error:
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Module hellomod not found
At present I do not know how to do, completely according to the tutorial to write, but run up an error, prompt can not find the module!

Using the javac command:
`javac hellomod/src/module-info.java hellomod/src/com/horstmann/hello/HelloWorld.java`

Using the Java command:
`java -p hellomod -m hellomod/src/com.horstmann.hello.HelloWorld`

The directory structure looks like this:

```
JavaPractice
----hellomod
--------src
------------com.horstmann.hello
----------------HelloWorld
------------module-info.java
---------hellomod.iml
```

The editor used is IntelliJ IDEA Educational Edition, How can I properly use a manually compiled module?

Comment: When you want to compile manually, you also have to deal with the real directory structure rather than an IDE view. You should have nested directories `com`, `horstmann`, `hello` rather than a single `com.horstmann.hello` one. Further, there should be a `HelloWorld.java` file. The path in your command, `hellomod/src/com/horstmann/hello/HelloWorld.java` suggests that this is the case, but your posted “directory structure” is not helpful. After compiling there should be class files, but perhaps, your IDE doesn’t show them. In other words, either do manually or use the IDE, don’t mix them up.

Comment: @Holger Thank you for your answer! Your answer seems to make me think of something!Do you mean the module name must also be com.horstmann.hello? Then create the com.horstmann.hello package in the SRC directory, is that right?

Comment: Using `com.horstmann.hello` would be adhering to established conventions, however, it’s not necessary technically. First, you should use a command line tool to show the actual directory structure, rather than the IDE’s view to it. Then, source directory structures do not necessarily match the binary directory structures you use at runtime. Therefore, you usually want to use the `-d` option when compiling manually, to specify a different target directory and have a clear separation.